# WPF Design-time Data Binding to Sample Data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

*WPF, C#, .Net 4.52, Visual Studio 2015, MVVM, Prism/Unity, Telerik UI for WPF - so my listbox is actually a "RadListBox" control*

Based on the following class pseudo-structure which gets populated from database calls at run-time:

```
<Process>
    <Steps>
        <Step>
            <Submodules>
                <Submodule>
                <Submodule>
                <Submodule>
            </Submodules>
        </Step>
        <Step>
            <Submodules>
                <Submodule>
            </Submodules>
        </Step>
    </Steps>
</Process>
```

I have a view model with a property called **SelectedStep** which represents the current step.  It is of type **Step**.

I have a view with a listbox control whose **ItemsSource** property is bound to **SelectedStep.SubModules**.  Works great at runtime and shows me the list of submodules for the selected step.

But I want to see a list of sub modules at design time so I can style the list.  So I created some sample data in a file called Step.xaml whose structure looks exactly like this:

```
<Step>
    <Submodules>
        <Submodule>
        <Submodule>
        <Submodule>
    </Submodules>
</Step>
```

There is only one step defined because I'm only going to show a single step's sub modules at design time.  There's no selecting steps as there would normally be at run-time.

To be able to bind to the sample data, I added the following attribute to the listbox:
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=Step.xaml}"

With the listbox's ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedStep.SubModules}" which is correct at run-time, I don't see anything at design time.  I have to change it to ItemsSource="{Binding SubModules}" to see data at design-time.  But that breaks the view at run-time.

How do I overcome this issue since **SelectedStep** is not being set at design time?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Bind your design time data context with the same runtime instance

Comment: Do the bindings refer to the same instance? Then you'll have to "model" your view model in the design data source (Step.xaml), so that you have a `SelectedStep` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the `d:DesignData` to the `DataContext` property, so you have to pass your view model there. Step.xaml should look something like that:

```
<YourViewModel>
    <YourViewModel.SelectedStep>
        <Step>
            <Submodules>
                <Submodule>
                <Submodule>
                <Submodule>
            </Submodules>
        </Step>
    </YourViewModel.SelectedStep>
</YourViewModel>
```

Then your bindings should work like at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Alexander and also thanks Versatile and Haukinger.  Changing Step.xaml to reflect my view model worked for me.  I had started down this path late yesterday but it wasn't working for me because I was trying to put everything within the`<YourViewModel.SelectedStep>` section and was leaving out the `<Step>` (model) tag.  But this code snippet showed me what I was missing.  Thanks!